# On click event in lwc, how to display all the records returned from apex method in new sub tab

Tags: lightning-web-components

Can anyone please help me to achieve below. "On click event in lwc, how to display all the records returned from apex method in new sub tab".

Apex method: select id,casenumber,status from case. Let's say this is returning 50 records

Lwc html file: onclick View All button
Lwc js file: handle onclick (wire apex method,get all records returned from apex method). I achieved until getting apex method records in js file data/result. Now I'm stuck at displaying this list of records in new sub tab.

Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Please present the code you already have and point out exactly where and why you are stuck.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. This site isn't a place to get your work done for you, for free. The expectation is that you've made an honest attempt, that you will share that with us, and that you can narrow down a question to be about a single, very specific thing. If you're new to Salesforce (or a part/feature thereof), then https://trailhead.salesforce.com is going to be a better resource to help get you started.